# How to track down an undefined symbol

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, corba

I am currently stuck with some code I successfully compiled into a .so file. When I try to link my library to some code if fails with the following statement:

> undefined symbol: _ZrSRKN5CORBA3AnyERPN3RTT5corba4Math7MatrixdE

The only useful information I can get is that there is something with an object or a function that uses the following types: "CORBA::Any" (a regular corba type) and "RTT::corba::Math::Matrixd" (a type which is defined using one hh file and two cc files).

I would be interested in knowing where exactly in my code that symbol is generated and why it can't be found. I am suspecting that it represents a function defined in one of my cc files so here is how I compiled the whole thing:

> g++ -I{CORBA includes} main.cpp one.cc two.cc -L{CORBA libraries}

What debugging process should I follow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a Unix environment [c++filt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt) would be available on your system, this is how you would use it to demangle a function name:

```
c++filt _ZrSRKN5CORBA3AnyERPN3RTT5corba4Math7MatrixdE
```

I just used [`c++filtjs`](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/) since it supports both `g++` and `msvc++`, it came back with this:

```
operator>>=(CORBA::Any const&, RTT::corba::Math::Matrixd*&)
```

Comment: The prototype of my function is "operator>>=(CORBA::Any, const& RTT::corba::Math::Matrixd*&)". Is it normal that the comma is inverted? Do you think that could stem from the issue?

Comment: In fact I have two similar functions. The first one is "operator>>=(const CORBA::Any&, RTT::corba::Math::Matrixd*&)" and the second one is "operator>>=(const CORBA::Any&, const RTT::corba::Math::Matrixd*&)". I would say that it matches the first one.

Comment: @Flav I don't understand the inverted comma question and it does match the first once since the `const` qualifiers match.